# check isExpaned() on component retrieved by using class

Tags: extjs

I have one component in Ext JS with following configuration.

```
  {
    ref: 'reasonCodeField',
    id: 'reason-code-field',
    cls: 'reason-code-field',
    xtype: 'enumcombo',
    enumName: 'SCH.TrackingEventReasonCodes',
    allowBlank: false
  }
```

Now I want get this element and want to perform collapse() operation if it's expanded.

By using following code retrieving element by using Id and able to perform required operation successfully.

```
var reasonCodeField = Ext.getCmp('reason-code-field');
if (reasonCodeField && reasonCodeField.isExpanded()) {
  reasonCodeField.collapse();
}
```

But when I tried to retrieve the element by using class then unable to perform collapse() or isExpanded() operation, only hide() works with it.

```
var reasonCodeField = Ext.select('.reason-code-field');
```

**How can I perform collapse() or isExpanded() operation when element retrieved by class name?**

Comment: what version of Ext JS are you using?

Comment: @TomVaughan 3.4V